# Как на клиенте (html-страница) получать сообщения от сервера на вебсокетах?

Tags: websocket, сокеты

На своем локальном компьютере в IDE PyCharm запущен скрипт:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen()
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)
conn.sendall(b'data')
print('Отправили данные')
conn.close()
```

При подключении к сокету в консоль печатаются 'connected: + {addr}', отправляется строка 'data' и сообщение об отправке 'Отправили данные' и закрывается соединение.

Далее я хочу, чтобы в консоли html-страницы (файл располагается в той же папке что и файл с сервером) в вывелась отправленная сервером строка 'data'. html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9090/");
        socket.onmessage = messageReceived;

        function messageReceived(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда я открываю html-страницу, должно произойти соединение и получено сообщение. Однако, этого не происходит, хотя в консоли PyCharm:

> connected: ('127.0.0.1', 53646) Отправили данные

А в консоли браузера:

> test_socket.html:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9090/'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

В чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказали, Python запускает TCP-raw сокет, а браузер ожидает протокол WebSocket. Для решения данной проблемы был использовать модуль websockets. Код сервера следующий:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def hello(websocket, path):
    await websocket.send(message)  # str

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```